# How to make a dinamically collapsible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```js
import React from 'react';
import Collapsible from 'react-native-collapsible';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

import { Container, Nav, NavText, NavItem } from './styles';

export default function Cards() {

    let isCollapsible = false;

    return (

        <Container>

            <Nav onpress={() => {
                if (isCollapsible == false) {
                    isCollapsible = true
                } else {
                    isCollapsible = false
                }
            }}>
                <NavItem>
                    <Icon name="favorite" size={20} color="#fff"></Icon>
                    <NavText>Motivo 1</NavText>
                </NavItem>
            </Nav>

            <Collapsible style={{
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "#fff",
                padding: 10,
                marginTop: 5,
                marginBottom: 5,
                borderRadius: 20
            }} collapsed={isCollapsible}>
                <NavText>Teste</NavText>
            </Collapsible>



        </Container>

    );
}
```

I'm trying to make a collapsible based on the value of my variable isCollapsible, in theory when I press the Nav, the value of the variable must change, but doesn't working. (I'm new on react-native)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use state to maintain your component state, so component will re-render when state changes

```js
import React from 'react';
import Collapsible from 'react-native-collapsible';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

import { Container, Nav, NavText, NavItem } from './styles';

export default function Cards() {

    const [isCollapsible, setIsCollapsible] = React.useState(true)

    return (

        <Container>

            <Nav onpress={() => {setIsCollapsible(!isCollapsible)}}>
                <NavItem>
                    <Icon name="favorite" size={20} color="#fff"></Icon>
                    <NavText>Motivo 1</NavText>
                </NavItem>
            </Nav>

            <Collapsible style={{
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "#fff",
                padding: 10,
                marginTop: 5,
                marginBottom: 5,
                borderRadius: 20
            }} collapsed={isCollapsible}>
                <NavText>Teste</NavText>
            </Collapsible>



        </Container>

    );
}
```

Comment: I tried it like you said but unfortunately it still didn't work